# Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [K in Key]: 123; }'

Tags: typescript

```js
function hello<Key extends string>(key: Key): { [K in Key]: 123 } {
  return ({ [key]: 123 }); // as { [K in Key]: 123 }
}

hello<'myKey'>('myKey');
```

I don't get it why the code snippet above produces an error and `key` is treated as `string` in `[key]` instead of `Key`.

How can I solve it? I commented out a workaround but it just feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue with the dynamic key. This can be fixed by adding a separate function that will be responsible purely for this operation:

```
function put<Key extends string, Value>(
  key: Key,
  value: Value,
): { [K in Key]: Value };
function put<Key extends string, Value>(key: Key, value: Value) {
  return { [key]: value };
}
```

Testing:

```
function hello<Key extends string>(key: Key): { [K in Key]: 123 } {
  return put(key, 123); // no error
}

hello('myKey'); // no error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxFAPAaQKYE9HYAeU2YAJgM6IVQBOMYA5gDSIBqAhgDYjYB8ACgBQiRAGs8ALkQ5czEYgBu3XtM49s8gJTSA3ogDamRAxl4AumpXZEAXwDcQ0JFgIUaLHgLFSlanQYWdmtBCVxpWVZlDSsNLURdBVpsKBBaJH0DMMslaztHWyEncGh4JAALbC4uOE98IhJyKhp6JlCpM1wdBMNjU1kcgEYAJgBmOwSklLSkVCgBMNYR0a0CosrquAEAcgBbXFlt1aEgA)

Comment: So, the fix seems to be the separate function declaration. Wow, that feels so incredibly dumb :((